# Slickgrid pager within Dynamics CRM having one icon per line

Tags: slickgrid

I am developing an application which runs within Microsoft Dynamics CRM (MSCRM). Essentially in this environment web resources including HTML, JavaScript, CSS and image files are stored within the system the can be referenced on pages. I've got SlickGrid running but have an issue where the pager buttons each occupy a whole line.  The key part of the HTML is:

```
<div id="SPLocation" style="width:100%; height:80%">Grid</div>
<DIV id="SPPager" style="width:100%;height:20px;">Pager</DIV
```

but it looks like this:
!http://www.clew-consulting.com/Temp/SGIssue.png

(hope this image works). Note each icon occupies a whole row. I've checked all the styles and images and they seem fine. The icons are functional.
The cause is probably that display:inline-block is not being picked up but it is there in the style sheets. It could be something special to do with  the environment within MSCRM but the other markups all look fine.

Unfortunately I cannot run IE developer and show this part of the screen where I could inspect the CSS.

Anyone any ideas? I know I have not posted all information.

Paul

Comment: That looks like a possible CSS problem, did you change the `position:absolute` or `relative` or vice versa?

Comment: Did you include slick.pager.css?

Answer (score 0):

The pager styles are defined in **slick.pager.css** file.
Place this file in your css folder and add the following line to your html file 
(**do not forget to replace [path to your file] with your real path**):

```
   <link href="[path to your file]/slick.pager.css" rel="stylesheet">
```